# How does Camille etch words on her own back?

Tags: sharp-objects

One of the main themes of the limited HBO series, *Sharp Objects*, is that the main character, Camille Preaker, portrayed by Amy Adams, deals with childhood trauma by carving words into her own flesh.  Many of these words are symbolic to her experiences and are used to tell parts of her personal history.

It is revealed that she carved words clearly on her back. I think this would be physically impossible to do, but the character says that she doesn't let anyone see her carvings so it's not likely someone else helped her write these words.

Maybe a book reader would have more information on the topic?

Comment: As I remember, Thomas Jefferson invented a mechanical device that would duplicate his pen strokes when writing so he could mechanically make copies of his letters instead of writing them twice.  And there is a name I don't remember for a mechanical device to duplicate actions.  So perhaps Camille Preaker obtained or made a similar device so that she could write on paper and simultaneously carve the same writings on her back.

Comment: I think your comment, @M.A.Golding , requires a response about Occam's razor, but you might think I was either making a pun or being too cutting with my criticism.

Comment: There is a scene in one of the first episodes where she has to sew her jeans near the hip and she does that without taking them off, while sitting in a car and without even looking on her hand. I think this scene is supposed to show us that she is very dexterous and that over the years of carving the words on her skin she became very good in operating small and sharp objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wondered the same thing, how could she possibly carve her back? So I did some research... The answer doesn't quite satisfy my curiosity, but I guess it will have to do...

"To do that, Morot (Sharp Object's makeup artist) brought in a live model, who stood in front of a mirror and wrote out every single word on her own body using a Sharpie. "I wanted it to be not just as if an artist had written words on her, but as if she had carved them out on herself," Morot explained. "So the places where she can't reach, well, there are no letters. In some places the words are crooked, or stretched, because of her hands' position when she's carving herself. That's why there's this blind spot in the middle of her back, about six to eight inches wide by a foot tall, with no words, only a few scratches."
*Check Out How Sharp Objects Faked The 400 Scars On Camille's Body @ Refinery29 https://www.refinery29.com/2018/08/206265/sharp-objects-episode-5-scars-full-body-amy-adams?utm_source=sms

Comment: This answer needs more info. For instance, who is Morot? This person is not mentioned in the question, and not explained in your answer. Just quoting an article is not enough. Please, use your own words more.

Comment: I think this answer is very good, +1. I added an edit for Meat Trademark's comment. My assumption was always that whatever horrible traumatic event that happened to her as a teenager was responsible for a lot of the words, and not just her own self-mutilation, so this, and the work they did for accuracy, was very informative for me.